# Find and replace using Matlab

Tags: matlab

In the below, I put C, A, B just to make it easy to understand. The actual cell array doesn't have this type of headers.

I have a matrix [3 7 2 9 34; 10 9 7 34 NaN; 27 2  9  NaN NaN; 6  7  3  26  NaN]

```
C  A  B
-------------------
3  7  2  9   34
10 9  7  34  NaN
27 2  9  NaN NaN
6  7  3  26  NaN
```

and a matrix [2 3; 2 10; 2 27; 1 10; 1 6; 1 6; 2 10] that will look like

```
D  C
------
2  3
2  10
2  27
1  10
1  6
1  6
2  10
```

I want to get by finding and replacing using Matlab

```
D  A  B
-----------
2  7  2  9  34
2  9  7  34
2  2  9
1  9  7  34
1  7  3  26
1  7  3  26
2  9  7  34
```

If the column C of 1st cell array and column C of 2nd matrix were the same, this problem will be very easy.

But the fact that they are different makes this difficult for me.

I could do this using for and if. For example, if column C of 2nd matrix is 3, it will be replaced by 7 2 9 34.

But this was very slow. So I needed a faster code.

At first I thought of unique, but couldn't figure out how to lead to the desired result.

Comment: You need to clarify your question, and most importantly, once you've clarified it, you'll have to tell us what you've tried.

Comment: The output doesn't make sense

Comment: @CTZStef OK I will do that right now.

Comment: I suggest you provide some information on the type of input (cell array?)

Comment: It is still unclear how these values are stored. Does each cell contain a single value or a row (a vector)?

Comment: @Eitan_T OK I will try to post the original code right now.

Comment: Do you have the statistics toolbox? Then you could use datasets, which seem like they would work better for you. It sounds like you want to join on C.

Comment: @Try_Hard These are matrices.

Comment: @Eitan_T Now I could confirm these are matrices. So I guess it is clear now how these are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mat1 and mat2 are the first and second matrices you described, this should do the join you need with indexing functions.

```
[~, I] = ismember(mat2(:, 2), mat1(:, 1));
Output = [mat2(:, 1) mat1(I, 2:end)]
```

Comment: Thank you. And perhaps the second "mat" should be "mat1", right? :) Perhaps a typo?